# AppleScript and Numbers: Can't add value to cell

Tags: excel, numbers, applescript

I'm trying to merge data from various sources into Numbers.

I keep receiving this error message:

```
Can’t set «class NMCv» of "C30" to 8302.0.
```

This is the subroutine I am using:

```
on addViewsToNumbersSheet(userViews, numbersRow)
    tell application "Numbers"
        tell front document
            tell table 1 of sheet "Doc Data"
                log "Row: " & numbersRow
                log "Value: " & userViews
                set cellC to ("C" & numbersRow as string)
                set cellValue to userViews
                set value of cellC to cellValue
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end addViewsToNumbersSheet
```

The data prints to the log:

```
(*Row: 30*)
(*Value: 8302.0*)
```

I tried to just place a string in the cell and I received the same error message. What am I missing? I have a separate script and I am able to add values to this same sheet with it.

So then I logged the class, it was a `real`. After various conversion efforts failed I added a subroutine that returned an integer. I feel like I am killing a fly with a bazooka here.

```
on convertNumber(userViews)
    set aString to userViews as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
    set aNumber to text item 1 of aString as number
    return aNumber
end convertNumber
```

and my previous script now looks like so:

```
on addViewsToNumbersSheet(userViews, numbersRow)
    tell application "Numbers"
        tell front document
            tell table 1 of sheet "Prebid Docs"
                set convertedNum to my convertNumber(userViews)
                set cellC to ("C" & numbersRow as string)
                set value of cellC to convertedNum
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end addViewsToNumbersSheet
```

I did confirm that convertedNum is an integer.

And still getting the error message. Sigh. Any help would be great.

**Bigger picture:**

I am pulling view data from Google Analytics as an Excel file. In my Numbers file I have the doc path and date it was added to the repo in cols A and B. I now want col C to contain this view data. I match paths (from GA (in Excel) to repo path (in Numbers)), save the row that matched (from Numbers) and the value from Excel and want to add that value to the Numbers row, col C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set cellC to cell ("C" & numbersRow as string)
```